# Copy and paste data in Mac using terminal

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I used vbscript to copy and paste data in Excel through command line. I would like to perform the same work in Mac. Following is the vbscript, I've used for Windows:

```
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
    objExcel.Visible = True
    Set srcData = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("sourcefile.xlsx") 
    Set destinationData = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("destinationfile.xlsm") 
    srcData.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").copy destinationData.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    srcData.close False
```

I don't know how to do it in Mac. Please help me in converting the script.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only thing you need to change is instead of "sourcefile.xlsx" and "destinationfile.xlsm" you need to add the full Path. Be aware that on mac the path is written differently than on windows.

Windows EX: C:\Documents\sourcefile.xlsx

Mac EX:     OSX:Users:"Username":Documents:sourcefile.xlsx

On Mac you can get the username with the following code

```
Function GetUserName() As String
    Dim sMyScript As String

    sMyScript = "set userName to short user name of (system info)" & vbNewLine & "return userName"

    GetUserName = MacScript(sMyScript)
End Function
```

In your code this would look something like this:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set srcData = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("OSX:Users:" & GetUserName.GetUserName & ":Documents:sourcefile.xlsx")
Set destinationData = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("OSX:Users:" & GetUserName.GetUserName & ":Documents:destinationfile.xlsm")
```

You could also:

```
Dim xlPath As String
xlPath = "OSX:Users:" & GetUserName.GetUserName & ":Documents:"
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set srcData = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(xlPath & "sourcefile.xlsx")
Set destinationData = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(xlPath & "destinationfile.xlsm")
```

For me this worked just fine. Hope it works for you as well.

CU